# Samsung SCX-3405W scanner not detected

Tags: drivers, scanner

Apologies if I'm doing this wrong. I've asked a question about my scanner not being detected, and been directed to already submitted question and response. When wanting to reply to that the instructions say not to ask further questions, so I'm resubmitting.

I've tried both solutions suggested in response to the other question, but am being told that the downloaded drivers could not be detected (I can see them in my download file with a little padlock logo) and when I tried the install lib usb solution I was again told it couldn't be detected.

As is probably obvious, I'm very new to Ubuntu and have no experience in coding.

Comment: Instead of posting a new question, you should [comment in or edit your first question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398377/samsung-scx-3405w-scanner-not-working) and if enough information is obtained, your first question will be re-opened.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've done as suggested.